# How can i display the acceleration value of my spaceship?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While the game is running and i press none stop on the key p i see the spaceship moving faster and faster. But the value of the variable thrust is all the 5 never change. Then what value show and change that make the acceleration ? And what the thrust do ? If i change the thrust from 5 to 10 ?

I added to my spaceship a Rigidbody component.

The way i'm doing it is the right way to add acceleration to my spaceship ?

I want to display in the OnGUI the value of the acceleration each time i press the p key.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ControlShip : MonoBehaviour {

    public int rotationSpeed = 75;
    public int movementspeed = 10;
    private int thrust = 5;

    Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    void Start () {

        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Debug.Log("Acc Speed: " + thrust);
    }

    void Update () {

        var v3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f);
        transform.Rotate(v3 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("p"))
        {
            _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrust, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + thrust);
    }
}
```

Update

My script now after changes. When i press the p key the spaceship is gone fast and the value of the acceleration is 0 all the time in the OnGUI:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ControlShip : MonoBehaviour {

    public int rotationSpeed = 75;
    public int movementspeed = 10;
    private int thrust = 5;

    bool isPKeyDown = false;
    float acceleration = .0f;

    Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.zero;

    Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Debug.Log("Acc Speed: " + thrust);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        var v3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f);
        transform.Rotate(v3 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("p"))
        {
            isPKeyDown = Input.GetKey("p");
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(previousPosition, transform.position);
            float acceleration = distance / Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2);

            previousPosition = transform.position;
            _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, acceleration, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isPKeyDown)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + acceleration);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/48179/rigidbody-acceleration.html

Comment: why do you expect `thrust` to change, when you are never assigning a new value to it?

Comment: Simple childhood mathematics should tell you what thrust is doing (or not doing) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the beginnig, thrust is the value of the actual force ( a push force ) for your starship. So the bigger the value the stronger it "pushes" your starship.

If your script works then yes it is a good way of adding acceleration ( that depends on what you think )

To be able to show acceleration value when user pushes "P" key you should calculate the acceleration value ( [how to calculate](http://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/how-to-calculate-acceleration/), or just use @Dan Wilson answer/comment ).

Then you should modify your Update method:

```
public void Update(){
    isPKeyDown = Input.GetKey("p");
    // ... rest of your code
}
```

update your class members:

```
bool isPKeyDown = false;
float acceleration = .0f;
```

update your OnGUI method:

```
public void OnGUI(){
    if ( isPKeyDown ) {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + acceleration);
    }
}
```

and to calculate your acceleration and playing with rigidbody i would recommend using fixed update:

```
public void FixedUpdate(){
    // calculate acceleration here...
    acceleration = ... ;
    if ( isPKeyDown ) {
        _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrust, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Easiest way of finding out the acceleration:

```
// as a member field
Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.Zero;

// in update
float distance = Vector3.Distance(previousPosition, transform.Position);
float acceleration = distance / Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2);

previousPosition = transform.Position;
```

EDIT2:
[updated code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ed4MVrq4)

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the second answer ? I mean your calculation is the same as using rigidbody.velocity ? I'm asking since i'm not sure what is the difference if there is any between the two answers i mean for learning i want to know if there is and what is the difference ?

Comment: In the matter of calculating the acceleration there's almost no difference. But in overall this answer all of your questions and not just only how to calculate the acceleration value.

Comment: Could you look please at my question i updated it with my script according to your answer. But when i press the p button the ship is gone fast and the value of acceleration is all the time 0. I guess i did a lot of wrong stuff there. I added my script at the bottom in my question.

Comment: this: _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, acceleration, ForceMode.Acceleration);

Comment: should be : _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrust, ForceMode.Acceleration);

Comment: Last thing is why the OnGUI keep showing 0 ? The line: GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + acceleration); i used a break point and acceleration is 0 all the time. But if i'm using a break point inside the Update i see that the acceleration value is changed.

Comment: In Update just change "float acceleration ... " to "acceleration ... " just because you have 2 vars with the same name, 1 in class ( object ) scope and one in method scope

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is velocity. And to see the acceleration over a specific time interval you need to compare the difference in velocity divided by the time between them. The value 5 you're printing is the value you add, not the value of the spaceship.

```
acceleration = (rigidbody.velocity - lastVelocity) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
lastVelocity = rigidbody.velocity;
```

[Further reading with this example here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/48179/rigidbody-acceleration.html)